# Setting Top dynamically not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

```
var topvalue=document.getElementById("lvl1App").scrollTop-2;
$('thead.fixedheader2 th').css({
    "position":"relative",
    "top": topvalue,
    "height":"10px",
    "background-color":"#CCCC99"
});
```

the backgroud color is applying to each th but top is not getting set in firefox. It is working in all other browser IE10,IE11,Chrome,Safari but not in firefox,

Comment: what happens if you `console.log` the `topvalue`? Firefox is quite strict when it comes to editing table CSS. If you inspect the element is the CSS being applied and not showing, or not being applied?

Comment: topvalue is  papulating. there is no error in console.I am setting the top  value on scroll event. var topvalue=document.getElementById("lvl1App").scrollTop-2;  "lvl1App"   is the div id.

Comment: If I get the value after applying CSS $('th').each(function (index) { var tt=$(this).css('top'); alert(tt); });    it is printing the correct value of top but it is not getting applied to the th element of the table